# Developing a testing tool

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am developing a testing tool.
Is it possible to add JUnit functionality to a java application so that the application (itself) can run test cases against a specified java code. In a more specific way, the application takes a folder of test cases, and the code to be tested, it then runs the test cases against that code.

if it is possible, what is the required libraries to include in the application?

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you want to do this without JUnit?  Are you looking into writing your own testing framework?

Comment: Yes, actually I want add do this functionality into a java application.

Comment: Usually unit-testing isn't part of the application itself, but is used to just makes sure that your application code is correct and everything does what you expect it to do.  That being said if you're writing an application/library to test other applications then maybe this makes sense.  Are you sure you're going down the right path?

Comment: @JNYRanger Well, if i want my application to run test cases on a other java code or program, the application will take a set of written test cases and run these tests against the code to reveal any faults in it. if this can be done by just importing a library in the application it would be great.

Comment: Sorry @Anas for the back and forth, I'm just trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  An application itself doesn't usually run test cases, but instead you run test cases ON an application/library.Based on what you just said in your comment you'd have to do lots and lots of reflection.  Have you done unit-testing previously?  It sounds like JUnit would do exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: I think i will try to consider JUnit as a solution, it is sure that using it is less complicated than designing something form scratch.
Thank you very much @JNYRanger for your effort of helping :) 
I Appreciate that.

Comment: No problem Anas.  Good luck!  Here's a good JUnit tutorial to get you started:  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You can execute JUnit tests from the code if that is the problem.
It's simple.

```
public Result runTest(Class<?> testClass, String testcaseName) {
  JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
  Result result = jUnitCore.run(Request.method(testClass, testcaseName));
  return result;
}
```

Another testing framework is TestNG.

If you don't want to use a testing framework you will need to identify test cases and execute them using reflection.